# MySQL error при INSERT

Tags: php, mysql

Не добавляет элемент в таблицу и пишет, что неверный синтаксис

```
if (!empty($_FILES['image_1']['name'])) {
    if ($_FILES['image_1']['error'] == 0) {
        if (substr($_FILES['image_1']['type'], 0, 5) == 'image') {
            $image = file_get_contents($_FILES['image_1']['tmp_name']);
            $image = mysql_escape_string($image);
            $images[$i] = $image;
            $i++;
        }
    }
}

mysql_query("INSERT INTO `images` (content) VALUES ($images[0])")
```

Comment: А что в переменной `$images[0]`?  И может ошибку то же напишите в вопросе?

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '????\0JFIF\0\0H\0H\0\0??\0C\0\n\r \n\n\r\r' at line 1 - ошибка

Comment: Еще одно, в вопросе явно напишите конкретно что находиться в `$images[0]`?

Comment: `"INSERT INTO \`images\` (content) VALUES ('".$images[0]."')"`

Comment: Спасибо, заработало